# MySQL 5.1 to 5.6: massive performance hit

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, mysqldump, myisam

Okay, this is possibly three questions.  I want to move my existing MySQL 5.1 database using MyISAM to 5.6 using InnoDB for what I think are a host of obvious -- and possibly even good -- reasons.

This is on Amazon RDS, so my upgrade route is limited to dumping and recreating the database.

I will cheerfully admit I'm not a sophisticated DBA.

### Problem 1: Wow is that slow!

It takes about 15 minutes to `mysqldump` our 160-million-odd rows. (Show table etc is coming, hold your horses.)

It took something like 50 **hours** to load it into a mysql 5.6 instance with engine craftily sed-script-ed to InnoDB.

### Problem 2: Where are my *rows*?

`select count(*) from node;` on the current DB gives about 162 million.  On the 5.6, it gives about 93 million.  The load appeared to be successful, although I can't prove it; at least, there was no error message after the load terminated.

If it wasn't successful, that was *really* slow.

### Problem 3: *WOW* is that slow!

So, `select count(*) from node;` completes in about no time at all -- between 0.00 and 0.03 seconds by the query results -- on 5.1.  On 5.6 with InnoDB, it takes over a minute.  The explain makes it obvious this is because of a difference in the way the query is optimized -- but unclear why it's different.

### Tables and explains

#### MySQL 5.1

```
mysql> show create table node\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: node
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `graph` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `predicate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `object` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeindex` (`graph`(20),`subject`(100),`predicate`(100),`object`(100)),
  KEY `ix_node_subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `ix_node_graph` (`graph`),
  KEY `ix_node_object` (`object`(255)),
  KEY `ix_node_predicate` (`predicate`),
  KEY `node_po` (`predicate`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_so` (`subject`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_sp` (`subject`,`predicate`(130)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `node_search` (`object`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=550671861 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(id) from node;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
| 163426434 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> explain select count(id) from node;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### MySQL 5.6

```
mysql> show create table node\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: node
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `node` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `graph` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `predicate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `object` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodeindex` (`graph`(20),`subject`(100),`predicate`(100),`object`(100)),
  KEY `ix_node_subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `ix_node_graph` (`graph`),
  KEY `ix_node_object` (`object`(255)),
  KEY `ix_node_predicate` (`predicate`),
  KEY `node_po` (`predicate`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_so` (`subject`,`object`(130)),
  KEY `node_sp` (`subject`,`predicate`(130)),
  FULLTEXT KEY `node_search` (`object`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=481239575 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```

```
mysql> explain select count(id) from node;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | node  | index | NULL          | ix_node_graph | 103     | NULL | 79671827 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issues have nothing to due with the version of MySQL. It has to do with the Storage Engine.

## Answer to PROBLEM #1 : Wow is that slow!

Running mysqldump only touches data from the `.MYD` file of the MyISAM table. Thus, I do not find anything surprising about dumping 163 million rows in 15 minutes.

Loading data into Amazon RDS taking 50 hours is not shocking to me either. Why ?

Regardless of which server model you choose for MySQL RDS, InnoDB transaction logs (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1) are always 128M and are not allowed to be changed, not even which the [**RDS CLI**](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/2928/). I wrote about this before : [Local database vs Amazon RDS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21914/local-database-vs-amazon-rds/21919#21919)

All writes to InnoDB are written to the Double Write Buffer> You should disable it before loading : See my post [Possibilities to speed up InnoDB INSERTs and UPDATEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50799/possibilities-to-speed-up-innodb-inserts-and-updates/50825#50825)

Each chunk of rows from each INSERT is handled as a transaction with stuff being written through ibdata1's double write buffer and the transaction logs. Thus, the slowness.

## Answer to PROBLEM #2 : Where are my rows?

Look at the `nodeindex`. I can see it is a prefix index.

According to the [MySQL Documentation on `CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html):

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables.

I can almost guarantee that any row where the length of `graph,subject,predicate,object` exceeds 767 did not make it into the InnoDB table .

## Answer to PROBLEM #3 : Wow is that slow!

This is due to the Storage Engine.

When you run `select count(id) from node;` against a MyISAM, MyISAM cheats and reaches into the `.MYD` header to get the row count. Thus, the running time for getting a row count is not a function of the actual numbers of rows. That's way the MySQL Query Optimizer optimizes away all standard mechanisms and gives you a row count.

When it comes to InnoDB, because it does not store the row count, a table must be fully scanned each time : See my post [Why doesn't InnoDB store the row count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count/17992#17992)

## SUGGESTION

I would not import it as InnoDB. I would import is MyISAM first. Then, convert all your MyISAM tables to InnoDB. Before converting it, you may have to change the `nodeindex` or get rid of it altogether. Otherwise, you will lose the rows upon conversion.

See my post [Which first: upgrade mysql version or convert storage engine?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9414/which-first-upgrade-mysql-version-or-convert-storage-engine/9422#9422) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm.  I've been planning to redo the DB for a while, replacing the massive VARCHARS -- which only have in the neighborhood of 50 distinct values -- with an index to another table, and move the FULLTEXT to a separate table.  It kind of sounds like I'm not going to get much out of InnoDB without biting the bullet on that.